# Why am I receiving "AttributeError: module 'image' has no attribute 'Image'"?

Tags: python, getpixel

When I try to execute the program below:

```
import image
img = image.Image("LutherBellPic.jpg")

print(img.getWidth())
print(img.getHeight())

p = img.getPixel(45, 55)
print(p.getRed(), p.getGreen(), p.getBlue())
```

I keep receiving the following error:

```
AttributeError: module 'image' has no attribute 'Image'
```

Comment: What `image` module are you using?

Comment: Nested Iteration: Image Processing The RGB Color Model

Comment: Never heard of it. Regardless, check the its documentation for find examples of using it — because from the information provided, it looks like you're merely not using it correctly.

Comment: https://fopp.umsi.education/books/published/fopp/Iteration/NestedIterationImageProcessing.html

Comment: You could `print(image.__file__)` to see if its the right module. And `help(image)` to see what functions / classes are available.

Comment: @tdelaney coincidentally, the image package has an "Image" class as well. So, that was probably why he got confused. Avishek Chatterjee welcome to stackoverflow, if the answer you received solved your issue, you can mark it as "correct" by clicking on the check mark beside the answer, to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.

Answer (score 15):

Instead of the `cImage` package, you installed the `image` package.

Hence, you have to uninstall the wrong package, using this command:

```
pip uninstall image
```

and install the correct one, using this command:

```
pip install cImage
```

Details on each package may be found in the [Python Package Index](https://pypi.org/) repository.

Ιn brief:

**`image package:`** image processing library for the Python-based web framework `Django`.

**`cImage package:`** image processing library for Python.